# при вызове метода session.update поле id из базы не обновляется, а устанавливается в 0

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Не могу никак понять в чем может быть дело.
Есть класс сущности

```
package localgroup.employeeweb.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    private int employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String departmentId;
    private String jobTitle;
    private Gender gender;
    private java.sql.Date dateOfBirth;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "department_id")
    public String getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(String departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "job_title")
    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }

    @Column(name = "gender")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
```

Есть вот такой вот класс DAO

```
package localgroup.employeeweb.dao;

import localgroup.employeeweb.entity.Employee;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Repository("EmployeeDao")
@Transactional
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(int page) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Employee> query = session.createQuery("FROM Employee order by employeeId", Employee.class);
        query.setFirstResult(10*(page-1));
        query.setMaxResults(10);
        List<Employee> employees = query.getResultList();
        return employees;
    }

    @Override
    public int countEmployees() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session.createQuery("select count(*) from Employee ", Number.class).getSingleResult().intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
//        employee.setDateOfBirth(new java.sql.Date(employee.getDateOfBirth().getTime()));
        session.persist(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.delete(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployeeById(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Employee employee = session.get(Employee.class, id);
        session.delete(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        employee.setEmployeeId(session.get(Employee.class,employee.getEmployeeId()).getEmployeeId());
        session.update(employee);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployeeById(Integer employeeId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session.get(Employee.class, employeeId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeByName(String firstName, int page){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Employee WHERE firstName = :firstName");
        query.setFirstResult(10*(page-1));
        query.setMaxResults(10);
        query.setParameter("firstName", firstName);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Класс контроллер

```
package localgroup.employeeweb.rest;

import localgroup.employeeweb.entity.Employee;
import localgroup.employeeweb.service.EmployeeService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    private int page;
    private final EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

@GetMapping("/employees")
public ModelAndView getAllEmployees(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") int page) {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmployees(page);
    int countEmployees = employeeService.countEmployees();
    int countPages = (countEmployees + 9) / 10;
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("employees");
    modelAndView.addObject("page", page);
    modelAndView.addObject("countEmployees", countEmployees);
    modelAndView.addObject("countPages", countPages);
    modelAndView.addObject("employeesList", employees);
    this.page = page;
    return modelAndView;
}

@GetMapping("/name")
public ModelAndView getEmployeeByName(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
                                      @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1", required = false) int page) {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getEmployeeByName(name, page);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("/employees");
    int countEmployees = employees.size();
    int countPages = (countEmployees + 9) / 10;
    modelAndView.addObject("page", page);
    modelAndView.addObject("countEmployees", countEmployees);
    modelAndView.addObject("countPages", countPages);
    modelAndView.addObject("employeesList", employees);
    return modelAndView;
}

@GetMapping("/employee")
public ModelAndView getEmployeeById(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id) {
    Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("id");
    modelAndView.addObject("employee", employee);
    return modelAndView;
}

@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
public ModelAndView editPage(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("editPage");
    modelAndView.addObject("employee", employee);
    return modelAndView;
}

@PostMapping("/edit")
public ModelAndView editEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
    employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/employees");
    modelAndView.addObject("page", page);
    return modelAndView;
}

@GetMapping("/add")
public ModelAndView addPage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("editPage");
    return modelAndView;
}

@PostMapping("/add")
public ModelAndView addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
    int countEmployees = employeeService.countEmployees();
    int page = (countEmployees + 9) / 10;
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/employees");
    modelAndView.addObject("page", page);
    return modelAndView;
}

@GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
    int countEmployees = employeeService.countEmployees();
    int page = ((countEmployees - 1) % 10 == 0) && countEmployees > 10 && this.page == (countEmployees + 9) / 10 ?
            this.page - 1 : this.page;
    employeeService.deleteEmployee(employee);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/employees");
    modelAndView.addObject("page", page);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

}

Так вот. вытаскиваются данные с бд нормально, добавляются тоже все хорошо, а вот когда хочу обновить запись, выскакивает вот такая ошибка

```
    Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [localgroup.employeeweb.entity.Employee] with identifier [0]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [localgroup.employeeweb.entity.Employee#0]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [localgroup.employeeweb.entity.Employee] with identifier [0]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [localgroup.employeeweb.entity.Employee#0]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [localgroup.employeeweb.entity.Employee] with identifier [0]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [localgroup.employeeweb.entity.Employee#0]
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:287)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:804)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:639)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:712)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.updateEmployee(Unknown Source)
    localgroup.employeeweb.rest.EmployeeController.editEmployee(EmployeeController.java:79)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [localgroup.employeeweb.entity.Employee#0]
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2529)
    org.hibern
```

когда начинаю дебажить, видно, что она появляется из-за того, что при вызове метода update(employee) id не обновляется а устанавливается в 0. В чем ошибка, помогите кто знает.

...ах да, чуть не забыл. вот такая бд(на PostgreSQL)

```
    create table employees
(
    employee_id   integer default nextval('id_seq'::regclass) not null
        constraint employee_pkey
            primary key,
    first_name    varchar(30)                                 not null,
    last_name     varchar(30)                                 not null,
    department_id varchar(30)                                 not null,
    job_title     varchar(30)                                 not null,
    gender        varchar(10)                                 not null,
    date_of_birth date                                        not null
);

alter table employees
    owner to admin;
```

Смею предположить что связано все это с полем ID в базе данных...

метод EmployeeService, правда там ничего такого нет

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    private final EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeDao employeeDao) {
        this.employeeDao = employeeDao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employeeDao.addEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteEmployeeById(Integer id){
        employeeDao.deleteEmployeeById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employeeDao.deleteEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employeeDao.updateEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Employee getEmployeeById(Integer employeeId){
        return employeeDao.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeByName(String firstName, int page){
           return employeeDao.getEmployeeByName(firstName, page);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public int countEmployees() {
        return employeeDao.countEmployees();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(int page) {
        return employeeDao.getAllEmployees(page);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы принципиально не используете генерацию ID при помощи Hibernate через `@SequenceGenerator(..)` ?, тогда бы и в БД ничего прописывать не надо было

Comment: А так же почему вы не используете спринговый JpaRepository<T,ID>? Там из коробки есть все простые методы: T findById(<ID> id), List<T> findAll() , count, delete, save, там же есть встроенная поддержка Pageble и Sort. Тогда бы ваш репозиторий значительно упростился. Просто хочется понять - это было принципиальное решение, и если да то с чем оно было связано?

Comment: Можно только сказать что в метод updateEmployee(Employee) прилетает employee с id = 0. Сервис EmployeeService  через который это прилетает вы не выложили.

Comment: Да нет, не принципиально было выбрано такое решение. Я просто совсем еще новичок в этом деле. Может подскажите как лучше все тогда организовать?

Comment: так будет правильнее?  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq", sequenceName = "id_seq", allocationSize = 1)

Comment: Да. Я напишу пример тогда

Comment: и что в таком случае в БД писать для ключа?
просто если написать такое: 'ALTER TABLE public.employees
    ADD COLUMN employee_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 );' тогда даже добавление в базу не работает, выскакивает вот такая ошибка:org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: вставить данные в столбец "employee_id" нельзя
  Подробности: Столбец "employee_id" является столбцом идентификации со свойством GENERATED ALWAYS.
  Подсказка: Для переопределения укажите OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE.

Comment: В том то весь и фокус что ничего, hibernate сам управляет сиквенсом

Comment: т.е. просто employee_id   integer not null
        constraint employee_pkey  primary key

Comment: скажу больше. можете не создавать таблицу, hibernate сам ее создаст во время запуска приложения. Со всеми ключами и ограничениями. Причем создаст в любой БД не только в POSTGRES.

Comment: просто если оставить поле ключа как я написал, то дбавлять - добавляет, а вот при удалении уже другая немного ошибка, правда суть таже "Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: а что нужно поменять чтобы БД сама создалась?

Comment: в application.properties надо добавить вот такую строку `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: так если БД удалить то в сущности мне подчеркиваются название таблицы и столбцов

Comment: это не страшно :)

Comment: Добавил пример в ответ

Comment: если останутся какие-нибудь вопросы киньте ссылку на проект на github или bitbucket

Comment: ок, спасибо. если будет время, гляньте то что есть сейчас
https://github.com/rodiyuk/employeeweb.git

Comment: вы не выложили на github сущности которые описали в вопросе

Answer (score 1):

для примера

Entity Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "seqEmployeeId")
@SequenceGenerator( name = "seqEmployeeId", sequenceName = "SEQ_EMPLOYEE_ID")
@Column(name = "employee_id")
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Length(min=3, max = 50)
@Column(name = "first_name",nullable = false,length = 50)
private String firstName;

@Length(max = 50)
@Column(name = "first_name",length = 50)
private String lastName;

//чтоб это работало надо будет вам создать сущность Department 
//в ней создать полe 
//@ManyToMany(mappingBy = "departments")
//private List<Employee> employees;
@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinTable( name = "employees_departments",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "department_id",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey( name = "fk_employee_department" ) ),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "employee_id",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey( name = "fk_department_employee" ) ) )
private List<Department> departments;

@Column(name = "gender")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender;

@Column(name = "job_title")
private String jobTitle;

@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

//===============================================================
// GETTERS AND SETTERS
//===============================================================

...
}
```

Все что пока нужно в репозитории

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long>{
}
```

Сервис

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService{

@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository repo;

public Employee getEmployee(Long id){
    return repo.getOne( id );
}

public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
    return repo.findAll();
}

public List<Employee> getEmployees( Sort sort ){
    return repo.findAll(sort);
}

public Page<Employee> getEmployees( Pageable pageable ){
    return repo.findAll(pageable);
}

public long getCountEmployees(){
    return repo.count();
}


public Employee save(Employee employee){
    return repo.save(employee);
}

public void delete(Employee employee){
    repo.delete( employee );
}

}
```

И REST Contoller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController{

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@GetMapping
public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
    return employeeService.getEmployees();
}

@PostMapping
public @ResponseBody Employee createEmployees(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    return employeeService.save( employee );
}

}
```

Я не все ваши методы писал, но там чисто механическая работа.

Comment: не совсем понял 
//чтоб это работало надо будет вам создать сущность Department 
//в ней создать полe 
//@ManyToMany(mappingBy = "departments")
//private List<Employee> employees;
@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinTable( name = "employees_departments",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "department_id",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey( name = "fk_employee_department" ) ),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "employee_id",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey( name = "fk_department_employee" ) ) )
private List<Department> departments; 
мне надо одна таблица

Comment: в сущности Departments будет только два поля? его id и список сотрудников?

Comment: На практике просто как правило сотрудник может числится в нескольких отделах как и в каждом отделе по несколько сотрудников. Если минимум то три поля в id, name, employees Ну если не хотите оставьте поле departmentId как у вас было.

Comment: а все-таки, с помощью метода что у меня, можно как-то исправить редактирование?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, нашел ошибку. Ошибка оказалась синтаксическая. В файле editPage.jsp просто передавал не employeeId, а id. Вот поэтому у меня и считывался null.